# Echo out php contents

Tags: php

I was wondering if functions like `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` exist except they grab the raw PHP code too.  All the files are local so I assume something would exist for this.  The only other solution I thought of for this was using the FTP library.  If anyone knows a way around this please let me know!  Thanks.

Example:

code.php

```
<?php
echo 'hello world';
```

text.php

```
<textarea>
<?php
echo file_get_contents('code.php');
?>
</textarea>
```

Should output:

```
<textarea>
<?php
echo 'hello world'; //isn't actually executed, just displayed as raw text
</textarea>
```

Comment: they should grab the php source if you open a local file.

Comment: Getting the PHP source of a page has nothing to do with choice of function. You can get the PHP source for a local file on the same server as your script; you cannot get the source for a remote page unless the server serves it to you.

Comment: Not for me... thanks anyways @DanielA.White

Comment: please post your code then!

Comment: I understand that, I guess I was a little vague with my wording.  I mean get the php source as a web editor would.  @meagar

Comment: Posted an example of what I mean to try and clear things up, sorry about that! @DanielA.White

Comment: That should work - although this has some security implications you might want to be careful.

Comment: <?php echo file_get_contents('code.php'); ?> will do it.

Comment: Forgot to put in the echo for the example, doesn't work :/ @Ananth    
Do I need to enable something in `php.ini` @DanielA.White

Comment: are you trying to get the PHP code or the HTML generated by the php code?

Comment: The php code @JonathanCrowe

Comment: @julienhaversano : I test it. Your code is working . the raw text is inside <textarea><?php
echo 'hello world';
</textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only a test not a answer (will be deleted)

index.php

```
<textarea rows="10">
<?php
echo file_get_contents('code.php');
?>
</textarea>
```

code.php

```
<?php
echo 'hello world';
echo 'textline 3';
```

output
IE8

[image]

show sourcetext IE8

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape HTML chars:

```
echo htmlentities( file_get_contents('code.php') );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your above example this would work:

code.php

```
<?php
echo 'hello world';
```

text.php

```
<textarea>
    <?php include('code.php'); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: This will put "hello world" but he is looking for"<?php
echo 'hello world';

He wants to print the "source code" not the rendered output.